# Set model field of child class as primary_key in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have an abstract model class:

```
class AbstractClass(models.Model):
    filename_base = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Is it possible to make a child class with `primary_key` set to this field without rewriting the field definition itself? I've tried the class definition below,

```
class ChildClass(AbstractClass):
    filename_base.primary_key = True
```

but it raises `NameError: name 'filename_base' is not defined`

Comment: As i understand you want to do something like this ` filename_base = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True, primary_key = True)`, am I right?

Comment: The point is that I need this field to have `primary_key = False` in the AbstractClass, and `primary_key = True` in the ChildClass, without rewriting the whole `models.CharField()` definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps.

```
class ChildClass(AbstractClass):
    pass
ChildClass._meta.get_field('filename_base').blank = False
ChildClass._meta.get_field('filename_base').null = False
ChildClass._meta.get_field('filename_base').primary_key = True
```

And Primary key should be blank=False and null=False.

Note: in `AbstractClass` id already has primary key my answer is for NameError.

Comment: Thank you very much! It solved the problem perfectly. I've never seen examples of using the `_meta` attribute before, but it turns out to be a [well documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/meta/) API